# How can I change the scale in two particular ranges of values in a graphic?

Tags: graphics

The graphic of this function is very condensed between $0\leq n\leq 500$. But it is more expansive among $500\leq n\leq 5000$.

How can I change the scale in two particular ranges of values in a graphic?

```
ListPlot[Table[Sin[50/n^2], {n, 1, 50, 0.01}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[Sin[50/n^2], {n, 1, 50, 0.01}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
ListPlot[Table[Sin[50/n^2], {n, 1, 50, 0.01}], 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ListPlot[
 Table[Sin[50/n^2], {n, 1, 50, 0.01}],
 Epilog -> Inset[ListPlot[
    Table[Sin[50/n^2], {n, 0.01, 1, 0.001}],
    Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red], {2800, .5}]
 ]
```

Of course you can place the Inset wherever you like by changing the coordinates.

Adjust the parameters as you like in the following:

```
ListPlot[
 Table[{n, Sin[50/n^2]}, {n, 1, 50, 0.01}],
 Epilog -> Inset[ListPlot[
    Table[{n, Sin[50/n^2]}, {n, 0.01, 1, 0.001}],
    Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 3, 
    ImageSize -> 100], {30, 0.5}],
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```